# Maximum Internet Bandwidth per User

Tags: networking, cisco, wifi, bandwidth

My question pertains to network bandwidth outside our local LAN.

We have a 10Mbps internet connection provided by our ISP.  We need to setup a wireless connection and the plan is to add a 54Mbps wireless router to our 10Mbps LAN. Approximately 30 pax/users will connect into this wireless router.

What is maximum speed each user can get if they are all using or browsing the internet at the same time?  For example, if each one is downloading a 10MB web portal applet over the internet in the morning when first logging on.

Comment: The maximum speed they can get is 10Mbps.

Answer (score 2):

Raw straight answer? About 24 seconds for a 1MB file per user. But 10Mbps divided by 30 concurrent users for web browsing is going to be extremely tight. Ignoring for a moment that WiFi will bring it's own congestion issues the resulting performance is going to hugely depend on the type of internet traffic consumed.

If it is streaming HD video for all, it's going to be a disaster to chop that into usable chunks. Traditionally the first port of call for low bandwidth was to implement an internet caching services. Personally I've experience of Squid proxy and it's very good. The main issue is it will struggle with TLS/SSL traffic nor streaming traffic, so whilst it can have a fantastic savings for downloads, that doesn't make up a lot of modern internet traffic.

In order to make the traffic usable you'll probably need to restrict some types of traffic such as youtube. If your router allows it, I would recommend setting some sort of QoS (Quality of Service) to ensure that important traffic is given a higher priority than trvial traffic.

Try and host your own content where possible to save internet transit via local servers for typical files. Have a look at Self-Hosted/Hybrid alternatives to typical cloud systems and storage.

Another strategy is to utilise your bandwidth at night time when it would otherwise not be in use by scheduling tasks to happen outside of normal hours that aren't time critical.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that easy to answer.  As gsmitheidw pointed out, 10mb divided by 30 would get you in the ball park, but you have to consider other overhead such as people checking email, or other network congestion.

If your users really need to be downloading 10mb files once per day or periodically, I would seriously consider upgrading your internet connection.  I assume that the 30ish users do not make up the entirety of your network.  Even if it is just half of your network, 60 connections sharing a 10mb pipe has got to be painful.

Also, consider an 802.11ac wireless router.  The 802.11g router you have is built on technology that is more than 10 years old.  You should be planning for the future, not just trying to satisfy current needs.  You will be forever be playing catch-up.  Doing it right the first time will save you and your company many headaches in the immediate and long term future.

**The short answer:**  consider upgrading your internet as well as a faster wireless router for as many users as you are supporting.